# Places of Interest not showing in Android Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-manifest, google-places-api

So I am following a tutorial to find places of interest: [LINK](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-google-places-integration--mobile-16054). I turn my Places API & Google Maps V2 ON in Google Console. I have my API Key and everything set correctly, because my map does comes up and my current location. But the places never show. I see no error in the logcat as well.

Heres my code:

MapsActivity.java

```css
package indabutt.com.indabuttalpha;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private LocationManager locMan;
    private Marker userMarker;
    private Marker[] placeMarkers;
    private final int MAX_PLACES = 10;
    private MarkerOptions[] places;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void updatePlaces(){
        //Update Location
        locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        double lat = lastLoc.getLatitude();
        double lng = lastLoc.getLongitude();
        LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat,lng);

        if(userMarker!=null) userMarker.remove();

        userMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(lastLatLng)
        .title("You are here!")
        .snippet("I am here BITCH!!!"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lastLatLng,10));

        String latVal=String.valueOf(lat);
        String lngVal=String.valueOf(lng);
        String url;
        try {
            url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="
                    +URLEncoder.encode(latVal, "UTF-8")
                    +","
                    +URLEncoder.encode(lngVal, "UTF-8")
                    +"&radius="
                    +URLEncoder.encode("5000", "UTF-8")
                    +"&sensor="
                    +URLEncoder.encode("true", "UTF-8")
                    +"&types="
                    +URLEncoder.encode("food|bar|church|museum|art_gallery", "UTF-8")
                    +"&key="
                    + URLEncoder.encode("AIzaSyBOY3eUzIL_Pz8NB9pSdRJcABiCw_kQ0M8", "UTF-8");
            new GetPlaces().execute(url);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        placeMarkers = new Marker[MAX_PLACES];
        updatePlaces();
    }

    private  class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        //fetch and parse place data
        protected  String doInBackground(String... placesURL){
            //fetch places
            StringBuilder placesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            //process search parameter string(s)
            for (String placeSearchURL : placesURL){
                //execute Search
                HttpClient placesClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try {
                    //try to fetch the data

                    //HTTP Get receives URL string
                    HttpGet placesGet = new HttpGet(placeSearchURL);
                    //execute GET with Client - return response
                    HttpResponse placesResponse = placesClient.execute(placesGet);
                    //check response status
                    StatusLine placeSearchStatus = placesResponse.getStatusLine();
                    //only carry on if response is OK
                    if (placeSearchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                        //get response entity
                        HttpEntity placesEntity = placesResponse.getEntity();
                        //get input stream setup
                        InputStream placesContent = placesEntity.getContent();
                        //create reader
                        InputStreamReader placesInput = new InputStreamReader(placesContent);
                        //use buffered reader to process
                        BufferedReader placesReader = new BufferedReader(placesInput);
                        //read a line at a time, append to string builder
                        String lineIn;
                        while ((lineIn = placesReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            placesBuilder.append(lineIn);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return placesBuilder.toString();
        }
        protected void  onPostExecute(String result){
            //parse place data returned from Google Places
            if(placeMarkers!=null){
                for(int pm=0; pm<placeMarkers.length; pm++){
                    if(placeMarkers[pm]!=null)
                        placeMarkers[pm].remove();
                }
            }
            try{
               //parse JSON
                JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray placesArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("results");
                places = new MarkerOptions[placesArray.length()];
                //loop through places
                for(int p=0; p<placesArray.length();p++){
                    //parse each place
                    boolean missingValue =  false;
                    LatLng placeLL = null;
                    String placeName = "";
                    String vicinity = "";
                    // int currIcon = othericon;
                    try{
                        //attempt to retrieve place data values
                        missingValue=false;
                        JSONObject placeObject = placesArray.getJSONObject(p);
                        JSONObject loc = placeObject.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
                        placeLL = new LatLng(
                                Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lat")),
                                Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lng"))
                        );
                        JSONArray types = placeObject.getJSONArray("types");
                        for(int t=0; t<types.length();t++){
                            //what type is it
                            String thisType = types.get(t).toString();
                            if(thisType.contains("food")){
                                // currIcon = foodIcon;
                                System.out.println("HELLO JAMAL THIS IS FOOD");
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(thisType.contains("bar")){
                                // currIcon = drinkIcon;
                                System.out.println("HELLO JAMAL THIS IS BAR");
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(thisType.contains("store")){
                                System.out.println("HELLO JAMAL THIS IS store");
                                // currIcon = shopIcon;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        vicinity = placeObject.getString("vicinity");
                        placeName = placeObject.getString("name");
                    }
                    catch (JSONException jse){
                        missingValue=true;
                        jse.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(missingValue) {
                        places[p] = null;
                        Log.e("<Jamal>", "Places is missing!");
                    }
                    else{
                        places[p]=new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(placeLL)
                                .title(placeName)
                               // .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(currIcon))
                                .snippet(vicinity);

                        Log.e("<Jamal>", "Places is HERE BITCH!");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(places!=null && placeMarkers!=null){
                for(int p=0; p<places.length && p<placeMarkers.length;p++){
                    //will be null if a value was missing
                    if(places[p]!=null)
                        placeMarkers[p]=mMap.addMarker(places[p]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="indabutt.com.indabuttalpha" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please message back with any potential solution!

Thank you

Comment: I tested your code, and I cannot get last known location, which means: `get LastKnownLocation` return `null object reference`. You may consider add a `LocationListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you bjiang, but I made a mistake when setting up my API Key, in order to use Places API, you need a **Browser Key** to get an accepted JSON response. I was using my API Key which give me a denial response.

I capture some logs regarding the JSON Response by putting this line of code in:

```css
                        while ((lineIn = placesReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            placesBuilder.append(lineIn);
                            Log.e("<Five>", lineIn);
                        }
```

Everything works great now :)